# Looking for a robot arm simulator

Tags: simulation, robotics

I am working on a robotic project but now I don't have the robot, so I need to continue on a simulator for its gripper and arm movements. I googled but I didn't find a suitable one.

I need to give the simulator the cartesian coordinations and to the gripper the appropriate velocities in order to perform the correct action.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should check [THIS](http://www.robotcafe.com/dir/Software/Simulators/) link for a suitable simulator.

Comment: How in the world can we help you with this? Chicken and egg scenario, if you could code the simulator, you wouldn't need it to code the robot.

Answer (score 1):

MRDS can be used to simulate almost any robotic parts as long you design and then import objects in the simulator. if you are familiar with a programming languages like java, c, c++ you can [check this list and choose a simulator](http://www.intorobotics.com/robotics-simulation-softwares-with-3d-modeling-and-programming-support/)